# How to unlock Rivals in Tetris Attack

Tags: tetris-attack

I have been playing Tetris Attack obsessively lately and I found out there are Rival characters you can unlock and play. I immediately prioritized my goals into getting those characters (Who doesn't want to be Petey the Piranha Plant?) but I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Steps

The "rival" characters can be accessed and used as playable characters, but only in the 
**2-P vs. mode**.

To unlock the four secret characters:

- Press **both L and R simultaneously** on both controllers on the character-select screen
- Press  **A** on controller number 2.

Pressing **L and R** on both controllers will cause 
the **rivals** to appear on the bottom of the screen.

Pressing **A** on controller 
number 2 will cause **Player 2** to select one of the rivals.  If **Player 2** does 
not wish to select a rival, he may press B.

---

## Source:

[Tetris Attack for Super Nintendo Entertainment System](http://www.gamefaqs.com/snes/588787-tetris-attack/faqs/15827)